# JSOUP - getElementsByTag AND getElementsMatchingOwnText

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I have HTML that has a picker where I need to find elements value by its text:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="content__controls js-content__controls content__controls_padding-top-15">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-9 no-left-padding">
          <form enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" method="post" class="form-inline" id="form" action="/Managment/Organizations/AddBinding">
            <div class="col-md-5 no-left-padding">
              <select class="form-control selectpicker" id="organizationId" name="organizationId" data-live-search="true" data-none-results-text="Nothing found">
                <option value="3">Text1</option>
                <option value="12">Text2</option>
```

For example I know `Text1` and need to get `3`.

I can get all option elements in this specific picker by tag

```
Elements elementsByTag = document.getElementById("organizationId").getElementsByTag("option");
```

Or I can get all elements in this picker matching text

```
String organizationName = "Text1";
Elements elementsMatchingOwnText = document.getElementById("organizationId").getElementsMatchingOwnText(organizationName);
```

But how can I apply both conditions simultaniously?

Comment: Which elements are you trying to select? What are you trying to achieve? It is not clear, at least to me. Can you describe which data you are interested in?

Comment: edited my initial post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like below might be what you are looking for:

```
String html; // your html

String search = "Text1";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);

Element option = doc.getElementById("organizationId").selectFirst("option:contains("+search+")");
System.out.println(option.attr("value"));
```

You can read more ablut the selector syntax here [Selector.html](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html)